# Where is the command-line options documentation for LLVM's lld?

Tags: linker, llvm, command-line-arguments

Where is the command-line options documentation for LLVM's lld?

I've looked at https://lld.llvm.org/index.html and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[LLD - The LLVM Linker](https://releases.llvm.org/5.0.1/tools/lld/docs/index.html) has this:

> LLD is a drop-in replacement for the GNU linkers. That accepts the same command line arguments and linker scripts as GNU.
>
> We are currently working closely with the [FreeBSD](http://www.FreeBSD.org/) project to make LLD default system linker in future versions of the operating system, so we are serious about addressing compatibility issues.

Comment: ugh, I missed that. Thanks. It's not completely obscure, but it's too bad they don't make it more obvious where to find the command-line syntax.